# Why does `append(x[:0:0], x...)` copy a slice into a new backing array in Go?

Tags: arrays, go, slice

On Go's [slice tricks wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks#copy) and Go libraries (e.g., [this example](https://github.com/tailscale/tailscale/blob/116f55ff6647d88f7f4a16237e28eda8d0e5b82f/util/multierr/multierr.go#L30-L33)), you sometimes see code like the following to copy a slice into a new backing array.

```golang
// In a library at the end of a function perhaps...
return append(whateverSlice[:0:0], whateverSlice...)

// In an assignment, as in the wiki example...
b = append(a[:0:0], a...)
```

Here's what I think I understand:

- All of the items in the slice that is the second parameter to `append` are copied over to a new backing array.
- In the first parameter to `append`, the code uses [a full slice expression](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Slice_expressions). (We can rewrite the first parameter as `a[0:0:0]`, but the first `0` will be supplied if omitted. I assume that's not relevant to the larger meaning here.)
- Based on [the spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Slice_expressions), the resulting slice should have the same type as the original, and it should have a length and capacity of zero.
- (Again, not directly relevant, but I know that you can use `copy` instead of `append`, and it's a lot clearer to read.)

However, I still can't fully understand *why* the syntax `append(someSlice[:0:0], someSlice...)` creates a new backing array. I was also initially confused why the `append` operation didn't mess with (or truncate) the original slice.

Now for my guesses:

- I'm assuming that all of this is necessary and useful because if you just assign `newSlice := oldSlice`, then changes to the one will be reflected in the other. Often, you won't want that.
- Because we don't assign the result of the `append` to the original slice (as is normal in Go), nothing happens to the original slice. It isn't truncated or changed in any way.
- Because the length and capacity of `anySlice[:0:0]` are both zero, Go must create a new backing array if it's going to assign the elements of `anySlice` to the result. Is this *why* a new backing array is created?
- What would happen if `anySlice...` had no elements? A [snippet on the Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/iojl6oAsvhI) suggests that if you use this append trick on an empty slice, the copy and the original initially have the same backing array. (**Edit**: as [a commenter explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74722224/why-does-appendx00-x-copy-a-slice-into-a-new-backing-array-in-go/74722343#comment131880116_74722224), I misunderstood this snippet. The snippet shows that the two items are initially the same, but **neither has a backing array yet**. They both point initially to a generic zero value.)  Since the two slices both have a length and capacity of zero, the minute you add anything to one of them, *that one* gets a new backing array. Therefore, I guess, the effect is still the same. Namely, the two slices cannot affect each other after the copy is made by `append`.
- This [other playground snippet](https://go.dev/play/p/5nEsnchfyCf) suggests that if a slice has more than zero elements, the `append` copy method leads immediately to a new backing array. In this case, the two resulting slices come apart, so to speak, immediately.

I am probably worrying way too much about this, but I'd love a fuller explanation of *why* the `append(a[:0:0], a...)` trick works the way it does.

Comment: You explained the operation in the first section, and again in the second section -- I'm not sure what you are confused about since you seem to have answered your own question. If you're looking for confirmation, yes, append creates a new array because you obviously can't extend a slice with 0 capacity.

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/builtin@go1.19.3#append *"If it has sufficient capacity, the destination is resliced to accommodate the new elements. If it does not, a new underlying array will be allocated."*. cap=`0` is NOT sufficient for non-empty slice, allocating a new array is necessary. cap=`0` is sufficient for empty slice, no need to allocate new array.

Comment: Your playground example isn't showing what you think either, the empty slices aren't pointing to the same backing array, they are pointing to a zero value used by the compiler, which is an implementation detail you're not going to see without digging in with unsafe. That is also the same value you'll see taking the address of an empty struct.

Comment: @mkopriva Silly as it is, if you want to post that as an answer, I'll probably accept it. Just say that the spec confirms my suspicion, I suppose.

Comment: @JimB Thanks: I'll update the post to reflect your point about the empty slices. Also, I suppose I rubber-ducked myself into an answer by writing this question. But, yes, confirmation helps. I was awfully confused about this at first, so I didn't trust my own conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because the length and capacity of anySlice[:0:0] are both zero, Go must create a new backing array if it's going to assign the elements of anySlice to the result. Is this why a new backing array is created?

Because capacity is `0`, yes.

---

https://pkg.go.dev/builtin@go1.19.3#append

> If it has sufficient capacity, the destination is resliced to accommodate the new elements. If it does not, a new underlying array will be allocated.

- `cap=0` is NOT sufficient for non-empty slice, allocating a new array is necessary.